# Setting the duration of Crouton messages in Android

Tags: android, crouton

I have started using Crouton messages instead of toast messages because I could configure the time duration. Is there any way I can keep displaying the crouton message until a particular event rather than specifying the time in definite units?

Answer (score 19):

You can set the Crouton's duration to `INFINITE` from within the `Configuration`. Then add an `OnClickListener` to it in which you call `Crouton.hide(...)` like this:

```
final Crouton crouton = Crouton.makeText(new Activity(), "foo", Style.ALERT)
    .setConfiguration(new Configuration.Builder().setDuration(Configuration.DURATION_INFINITE).build());

crouton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    Crouton.hide(crouton);
  }
});

crouton.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but can I call Crouton.hide(crouton) without the on-click listener? I mean to say, can I call just the hide function in an if-branch?

Comment: One more question, do the crouton variables have to be final? Or can we declare in some way using normal declarations. Because, currently, the show and hide methods give error if I try with non-final crouton variables.

Comment: To your first question. You can hide the Crouton any way you want. The second question: Yes, it has to be final, if you're trying to access it from an inner class.

Comment: After declaring the croutons in the way you have in the MainActivity class, I am calling an AsyncTask from which I call the show and hide functions from runOnUiThread in doInbackground() function. I keep getting null pointer exception related to croutons. Please tell me how to rectify this?

Comment: This is a different question. Please ask it and include the stack trace there.

Comment: how do i add it to a specific view                 Crouton.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected to the interned", Style.INFO, R.id.main_crouton).setConfiguration(new Configuration.Builder().setDuration(Configuration.DURATION_SHORT).build()).show(); like this ?

Comment: @KaustubhBhagwat this is a separate question.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer i want to set duration only .. but to a view i.e R.id.main_crouton which is a framelayout in my activity

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Crouton library, you can simply add a `view` and set an `onClickListener` to it. When the user click on it, the `view` is removed from the `Layout`.