# Crouton disable auto hide

Tags: android, crouton

I'm using [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) library and i'm trying to disable auto hide after finish duration. how can i disable that and can be hide when i want to hide that?

this is my code and i can't find some option to do that

```
crouton = Crouton.makeText(activity, AndroidUtilities.getString(R.string.please_wait_for_prepare_data, context),
        new Style.Builder()
                .setTextSize((int) AndroidUtilities.getAdjustTextSize(activity, context))
                .setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark)
                .build(), rootLayout);
crouton.show();
```

Comment: I find this link http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/

Comment: Too this link explains how to hide then https://stackoverflow.com/q/20234873/6848782

Comment: @RogerRV thanks sir, my problem resolve

Answer (score 1):

use [DURATION_INFINITE](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/de/keyboardsurfer/android/widget/crouton/Configuration.java) as duration for you Crouton, and set an `OnClickListener` on its `View`, using `setOnClickListener`. When the callback is called, call hide on your Crouton instance